# ISerializable and ViewState - Good or Bad?

Tags: asp.net

Is it a common practice to store ISerializble data in the viewstate?

I have a asp.net webpage with a telirik grid on it. To allow paging filtering etc, I want my data(Array of object) to be stored on client side to avoid run trips between client and server. So my intention is to make the object that are bind on the grid ISerializable and stored them in the Viewstatte. So, is it the best practice to so it or should I avoid this?

Thank in advance

Comment: ViewState does not avoid round-trips.

Comment: How will you access the ViewState data from the client-side?

Comment: @SLaks: you are right about ViewState, but it will stored the data so I wont have to go all the way through querying the database. 
@Marcie: In the aspx.cs I do the following : obj[] = Viewstate["aaa"] as obj[];

Comment: Which round trip do you care about, the post back (user client's browser to web server) or the sql call? (web server to sql server). Your strategy deals with the 2nd, not the first. This would have to be a very expensive sql call, otherwise, the much slower call (the http request and postback) will swamp the savings you get from fewer sql calls.

Comment: @MatthewMartin: I am talking about querying for like 500 records. This is not so huge I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bad practice to store list of database objects in the viewstate, because this will put load in your page and will increase the response time of the page.

Only page related data should be stored in the viewstate like **sort column** and **order of sorting** etc.

If the data is common for all the users you can cache the objects.

Comment: Ok but lets say I have paging on a datagrid, that would means that I should query the database each time the user click on a different page?

Comment: @Breach: Yes. What is the total number of rows you are retrieving?

Comment: @Breach: You should be querying the db each time the user clicks on the different page. If the data is not going to change then you can cache the data, however keeping it in viewstate will give serious performance problems.